# I'm having trouble with setting a timer to a recursive function that I want to stop running for too long in python

Tags: python, multithreading, recursion, timer

this is the first time I am reaching out with a question so hopefully I get the format right.

I am trying to limit the running time of my function (lets call it 'recursive_tsp_function') that is called from inside another function. This function recursive_tsp_function sometimes (not always) for unknown reasons keeps running infinitely.

**CONTEXT:**
Already, I tried implementing some sort of time checks like this

```
def recursive_tsp_function(parameters)
  start = time.time()
  ... (function here)
  now = time.time()
  if (now - start) > max_time: 
     return
  ... (function continues)
```

But for some reason my kernel in debugging mode keeps running the recursive function infinitely until I manually pauze the running and go on step by step in the debugger and than it does register the time checks and than stops the function like it should.

**NOW:**
Because that approach didn't work I looked a better method online and came upon working with threads. I now have the following method based an a simple online example:

'Countdown' is my timer function (in the same file as the 'above_function').
The structure of my function above 'above_function' you can see below (note that it threads the timer).

Also I added a 'check' function to the same file as the above_function that checks whether the timer has run out. I did this because there was a problem with referring to the global variable my_timer from the recursive_tsp_function which is located in a different file (I would think my_timer being a global variable would make it accessible from other functions but anyway that seems to be resolved for now)

```
def countdown(max_time_timer):
   global my_timer
   my_timer = max_time_timer
    
   for x in range(max_time_timer):
     my_timer = my_timer - 1
     time.sleep(1)`

def check():
    global my_timer
    if my_timer ==0:
        return False
    else: return True
    
def above_function(...):
    ...
    countdown_thread = threading.Thread(target = countdown(10))
    countdown_thread.start()
    route = recursive_tsp_function(parameters)
    ...
    return route
```

And than in a different file I have the recursive_tsp_function that would look something like this where I routinely run the check function from above and check whether my_timer is 0 yet:

```
def recursive_tsp_function(variables):
   ...
   if not check():
     return
   ...
   return recursive_tsp_function(variables)
```

The PROBLEM that I have with this setup is there seems to be no threading taking place, the timer first runs out and only than the function recursive_tsp_function would run. Naturally this function stops immediately because the timer is already on 0.

Thank you for being patient with my long explanation. If anybody got tips on how to tackle a timer on a function like this I would be very grateful.

Comment: _This function recursive_tsp_function sometimes (not always) for unknown reasons keeps running infinitely._ This is your real problem.

Comment: I get what you mean and you're right but the function I am referring to is a travelling salesman problem solving heuristic that I got from github. It has a lot of features that I do not understand and fixing what is going wrong there, eventhough it would probably be something tiny, would require me to understand everything in that script and I feel like just understanding what's happening would require a gigantic amount of effort from me that would not be well spend.

Comment: I run the above_function a lot, over 5000 times, and so when it does not give me a better route every now and then it doesn't really matter to me so I would prefer to evade the problem of solving the issues with the script

Comment: i wonder why recursive_tsp_function returns another recursive_tsp_function.

Comment: The recursive_tsp_function can also return a route but I tried to only write the essential parts of the function to make it recursive

Comment: with the Thread runs, there will be RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison.

Comment: The RecursionError has never come up while the function is stuck running. The function itself also limits the maximum depth so I don't get why the recursive_tsp_function would get stuck. I can't understand much from debugging so I for now I gave up on trying to fix the recursive_tsp_function

Answer (score 0):

you should create the [thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) like this.

```
# target is the callable object 
# args is the argument tuple for the target invocation
countdown_thread = threading.Thread(target = countdown,  args=(10,))
```

Comment: Thank you this has made the threading work :)

Answer (score 0):

What if you try

```
maxtime = int(input("What is the time for the timer?"))
import time
time_went = 0
for i in maxtime:
  time_went = i
  time.sleep(1)
```

And then instead of using `time_went == 0` you can use `time_went == maxtime`?